# App to App communication in Cloud Foundry

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry

Assume you want to deploy 2 apps of which one provides some API to the second application.

With services I'd just bind the service (or declare it as dependency in my manifest) to my application and hence get the information regarding host, port and credentials passed to my application (e.g. via env variables in node.js). Is there a similiar mechanism for application to application "communication"?

So far my approach is to use a RabbitMQ service (or any message broker/queue) which both applications are bound to and which I then use for cross-app communication.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a message broker, as you do, is definitely a viable solution. This allows for asynchronous communication. Yet you will have to take care of authentication yourself, as opposed to app <-> service communication, where authentication/authorization is established through through cloudfoundry service binding.

Another way would be to use a service registry for this. Both apps would register with the service registry and be able to discover each other.

You could try spring cloud service registry (Eureka) or consul. As for your message broker solution, this will not generate credentials for your apps, as a cloudfoundry service binding does.

Comment: Alright. So for me it somewhat feels like that you want to create a bunch of services (instead of applications only). And only the applications which itself are not consumed by any other part of your application (lets say a UI) are *actual* applications. This way you would get the security stuff "for free" as you can use bindings.  Do you agree?

Comment: We have to differentiate Micro-Services and Cloudfoundry services. CF services are usually used for off-the-shelf parts of your app, such as databases, message brokers, api gateways. In other words things that could also be used by other apps and are therefore made available to all CF users by a service broker. If you want to make parts of your app available as a CF service, then you would have to implement a service broker for these parts. But microservices are actually CF apps, that may register with a service registry. I guess microservices would make more sense for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

From your use case, for microservice to microservice discovery, you need Spring Cloud Services and Eureka.

I don't have much experience on nodejs. But some googling, will give you some articles. Here's one that may help you - https://www.npmjs.com/package/eureka-js-client

This article will give you an overview from Java and Spring perspective - https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/.